# can we use twilio for video calling in php application

Tags: php, video-streaming, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have seen documentation for rest api integration but there is only room creation and listing participant so how can I create whole video calling app using PHP or python as there are no documentation related to this on 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can create a whole Video calling app using PHP and [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video). The thing is, you need an interface with which to see the Video app too. This can be done in [JavaScript](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript), [iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/ios) or [Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/android).

You will need PHP (or Python, or any server side language) to [generate access tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens) so that your users can authenticate with Twilio Video.

To get started I recommend you check out the [Twilio SDK starter for PHP](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-php). This is a starter application with PHP that shows you how to integrate Video (and Chat and Sync).

Once you understand how the PHP fits in, check out this [getting started guide to Twilio Video in JavaScript](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript-v2-getting-started).

That should get you going. Let me know if there's anything else I can help with.

Comment: I have setup video calling using node js but it gives error you can read error log here https://urbeautytutor.com/quickstart/server/npm-debug.log

Comment: I get a 404 for that URL. Since you now have an application and a new error I recommend you ask a new question and I'll try to answer there.